# how to read gcc input from external file

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, g++

I'm trying to read the input for a c++ file `y.cpp` from the file `file.in` and save the result in `file.out` but I can't figure how to do it.

for example, if the following code was in `y.cpp`

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int x;
cin>>x;
cout<<x<<" was entered";
}
```

and the content of `file.in` was

```
56
```

I want a shell command to write `56 was enterdd` in file.out

What I did so far is compiling `y.cpp` and printing the result in `file.out`.

```
g++ y.cpp -o y.out
./y.out>file.out
```

But in my code, reading is from the terminal and not from `file.in`, and I want to read from `file.in`.

I searched for a piping method to pipe `file.in` content into the `g++` command instead of reading from the terminal. But I didn't find anything about piping input file. all what I found was piping source code into the compiler and not piping input.

I searched also for all the options of g++ that have `file` parameter but could not find aything to answer my question.

How can I do it?How to read c++ input from external file instead of reading it from terminal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
./y.out < file.in > file.out
```